# How do i center align my heading with css inline

Tags: html, css, web, styling

How do i center align with css inline

```css
.h1 {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

How do i center align with css inline

Answer (score 3):

we cannot use . for simple html tag.
Rember .is used for classes and # is used for id for accessing it through css.So only mistake you are doing is using (.) with your h1

```
h1{
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are doing in wrong remove `.` from `.h1` because you have not mention in you `h1` tag like `<h1 class="h1"></h1>`

> Note

1. `.` is used for class selector.
2. `#` is used for id selector.
3. `*` is used for all element

```css
h1{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that in CSS you are calling Header element ( h1 ) like it's an class ( using . ). When you want to style elements that don't have any class or id, call it with the actual element name.

See for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp

Like this:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing, you cannot use `.` for an html tag in a stylesheet.

> `.` is used when a class is assigned to the Html element

> `#` is used when an id is assigned to the Html element

> The name of the html element for eg: `h1` is used when you want to directly apply styles to the html tag

Now, **For inline css**,
if you want to align text in the center using inline css, then use the following `style:""` attribute.

```
<html>

<body>
  <h1 style: "text-align: center;">Test</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML with Bootstrap:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h1 class="col-sm-2">More Text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h2 class="col-sm-3">More Text</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h3 class="col-sm-3">More Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h4 class="col-sm-3">More Text</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h5 class="col-sm-3">More Text</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div, h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```